# Video Freeze in Chrome after 1-2 minutes in webRTC, working fine in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, apprtc

When i wrote the code 6-7 months back everything was working, with no issues what so ever. But recently when i tested it, In Chrome specifically video freezes after some time.
Calling from Android implementation.

Call is working fine in firefox, safari. 
If both devices are on same broadband, the issue happens about 1-2 minutes later, if anyone on 4G or cellular it happens instantly. My best guess is that chrome skips one frame to encode, and the drops all coming frames.

[image: chrome://webrtc-internals video sending graph]

Here is a screenshot of webRTC internals sending video graph, after it dropped, you can clearly see the drop in 'sending bytes' and 'constant line' in encoded frames.

I don't even have any idea about how to debug this, any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: were you able to figure this out? We are also facing similar issues, and are trying few things including setting the bitrate provided in this link - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/216, but no luck so far.

Comment: no, we couldn't. so we assumed it is a chrome issue and moved forward, right now we are using video call in webView for android.  
Using webView also trimmed app size since we no-longer need ejabberd libraries on android end.

Comment: Check your turn server, I also got the same issue, which was resolved by changing the turn server.

Answer (score 0):

How does the peerconnections iceconnectionstate look like? Does it go to disconnected and (after some time) to failed? 
See https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/ for an explanation for that part of webrtc-internals.

Comment: Hi Phillip, so after reading your link,
i added somequick handlers to print the changed states on every state change.

`pc.onsignalingstatechange = function() {
    console.log("New Signalign State: ", pc.signalingState);
};

pc.onicegatheringstatechange = function() {
    console.log("New IceGathering State: ", pc.iceGatheringState);
};

pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function() {
console.log("New IceCandidate State: ", pc.iceConnectionState);
};`

Comment: And this is the output: 
`11:14:50.041 (index):734 New Signalign State:  have-remote-offer

11:14:50.041 (index):734 New Signalign State:  stable

11:14:50.049 (index):744 New IceCandidate State:  checking

11:14:50.060 (index):738 New IceGathering State:  gathering

11:14:50.167 (index):738 New IceGathering State:  complete

11:14:51.223 (index):744 New IceCandidate State:  connected`

once video started, it is the states, you can see the final states, afte 40 seconds video freezed, and i didn't saw any more logs.

Comment: Final states were: stable (signaling), complete (ice-gathering) and connected (ice Candidate)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and as far as I know, this is a bug in Google Chrome version 56 and above. You can try downloading Google Chrome version below 56 it will work on the downgraded version. There are numerous bug reports filed with this bug and the interesting part is it is reproducible on Android's Google Chrome Application with version 61 and above.

Check out the following bug reports.

[video Freezes on Google Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Qu2SYBmohOw)

[Android Chrome 61, video freezes after connecting](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/issues/487)

[Chrome 61 on Android 6.01 or 7.0 Received Video Freezes](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769622)

[Video freezing issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/L3FH5kyEo1o)

Comment: Hi Somesh i have read all those issues before, and i think they are different from my situation since, web-to-web and app-to-app is working fine in both chrome-to-chrome, chrome-to-firefox, desktop-to-desktop, desktop-to-mobile. The only problem is web(chrome)-to-app

Comment: do you happen to know any demo or sample code, that does app-to-web video call, i want to compare my vars with them

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have a sample android app [here](https://github.com/someshkumar049/AndroidWebRTCGradle)

Comment: Ok somesh, i will try this app. and will let you know.

Comment: @Praveen were you able to find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Amit No, we ended up using webView on Android end too.